# EGit will not add an existing repository

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I recently upgraded to a new PC at the office. I have cloned my team's Git repository to a local folder, and I have installed Eclipse and EGit. In the EGit perspective, I click on "Add an existing local Git repository". In the pop-up that follows, I select my local repository and click finish.

The pop-up closes, but then literally nothing happens. There is no error message, warning, etc., but the repository is not added to EGit. I have done this before on previous machines without difficulty, and my team members are all up and running (and have been for some time).

We are running Eclipse 4.2.2 (this is the latest version of Eclipse that we are able to run, due to the requirements of a vendor plugin.) We are running EGit 3.7.1 (we have found that this is the latest version of EGit that works with Eclipse 4.2.2). This configuration has been in place for several years, so I doubt that the issue lies in the version of the software that we are using.

Thank you in advance for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out. I had been experimenting recently with some multi-line aliases in my config file. You can do it by placing a backslash at the end of each line. This works great in Bash, but confuses EGit. When I made all of my aliases single-line, then everything worked as expected.